# How to get power apps to handle folders in a list properly

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have a SharePoint Online list that uses folders with unique permissions. Each user can only see their own personal folder and the items inside. I set the default view to show content inside of folders rather than flat. In SharePoint, the user first sees their personal folder at the top level of the list. They click on the folder and add items inside of it in order to keep them private. Seems to be really tricky for a power apps beginner like myself to create that in power apps and I'm looking for some ideas on where to start.

I know I can make the start screen gallery be filtered by only showing things that have a content type of folder. Hopefully, this would respect permissions and show each user only their own folder like in SharePoint Then, when you click on the folder, it would take you to a gallery on another screen. But this screen would have to be filtered to only show items that relate to the folder clicked on. SharePoint does this naturally. So the second gallery would have to somehow be filtered by knowing what was clicked on to get to that screen. I don't want to make a screen or even a gallery for every user case.

Also, I need to make sure that any entries on the second screen are being entered into the person's folder rather than the top root. SharePoint seems to record it as being under that folder, but will power apps do the same?

Can anybody get me started or give me some ideas as to how to approach this? Maybe an article that solves a similar problem? I couldn't find one yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If users don't have directly access to share point is the best way for build your app, you may put all file in the same folder and filtered by a column with user informatcion, for example: column isFolder with values ["Yes", "No"] yo can filter and show in gallery only folders and column userEmail you can filter folders for a especific app user.

In case users have access to sharepoint you must create a connection for each user folder to collect files inside and show it in second screen and populate gallery with condictional (switch or if), for example: Gallery Property:Items = If(User().Email = FirstGallery.Selected.userEmail, colForThisUserName)

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand what you are saying (maybe not), but it seems as though it's what I was logically afraid of. I would have to create a case for every possible user. There could be hundreds of them or even x amount more. And maintaining that could get out of control. Maybe that's all that can logically be done. I don't know.

Comment: Oooh, if you have a lot of users the second case is not a deal for you